# How to retrieve table attributes in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm very new to PostgreSQL (and SQL as a whole) and I'm trying to find a way to view all attributes of a table. For example, say you have a table called "movies", I would like to see what attributes it has (e.g. movie_name, release_year).

I'm sure there is a simple command for it, but I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by *attributes* you mean *columns*, a standard approach uses [system view `information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html):

```
select column_name, datatype 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'mytable'
```

From a PSQL command line, you can also use `\d` (which stands for *describe*):

```
# \d mytable
```